# error en angular 7: Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular

Soy nuevo en angular, estoy siguiendo un tutorial al pie de la letra,todo va bien hasta que agrego las siguientes lineas de codigo( constructor(private modalService: NgbModal){} con su respectivo import)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que me genera en el navegador es

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at ng-bootstrap.js:146
at Module../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js (ng-bootstrap.js:148)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Module../src/app/todo/todo-list/todo-list.component.ts (main.js:294)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
```

Comment: Por favor, pega el código en la pregunta, no capturas de pantalla. Ya deberías saber que no podemos copiar código de una imagen, lo que dificulta cualquier prueba

Answer (score 1):

Encontré un [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816852/ng-bootstrap-typeahead-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function) similar a tu problema por si gustas verlo. De todos modos te explico tu problema.

Tu problema tiene que ver con la versión en la que estás desarrollando en Angular y la versión de la dependencia de NgBootstrap.

Si pudieses actualizar tu post para exponer tu archivo `package.json` que se encuentra en la raíz de tu proyecto, donde se encuentra la versión que instalas de Ng-bootstrap sería mejor. Sin embargo, te explico qué debes hacer:

1. Ver tu versión de Angular. Para esto, con la terminal desde la raíz de tu proyecto, ejecuta el comando `ng version`. Verás una línea que dice `Angular:` debajo de tu Sistema Operativo.
2. De acuerdo a tu versión de Angular, podrás instalar, o no, ciertas versiones de Ng Bootstrap. A continuación te pongo la tabla que se presenta en la [página oficial](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).

Antes de esto, tendrás que desinstalar el ng bootstrap que tienes actualmente con el siguiente comando `npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` desde la raíz de tu proyecto.

- Si tienes **Angular 8.0.0** en adelante,  puedes instalar cualquier versión, pero te recomiendo la más actualizada. Lo instalas con el siguiente comando `npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
- Si tienes **Angular 7.0.0**, deberás instalar la versión 4 más reciente. Actualmente es la 4.2.1. Lo instalas con el siguiente comando `npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@4.2.1`
- Si tienes **Angular 6.1.0**, deberás instalar la versión 3 más reciente. Actualmente es la 3.3.1. Lo instalas con el siguiente comando `npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1`
- Si tienes **Angular 6.0.0**, deberás instalar la versión 2 más reciente. Actualmente es la 2.2.2. Lo instalas con el siguiente comando `npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@2.2.2`
- Si tienes **Angular 5.0.2**, deberás instalar la versión 1 más reciente. Actualmente es la 1.1.2. Lo instalas con el siguiente comando `npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.1.2`

Todas las versiones más recientes de ng bootstrap las saqué de su [sitio de github](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/releases) en el apartado de releases.

Comment: Que tal Geronimo, bienvenido... Te recomiendo que elimines esta respuesta, ya que en realidad **NO LO ES**... te sugiero que lo hagas antes de que te reporten... Para más información date una vuelta por [answer]

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado Muchas gracias. No comentaba porque no podía. Sin embargo, sólo quería ayudarlo. Aún así, he actualizado mi respuesta en base al post que me has enviado. _«Asegurarte de que tu respuesta incluya la solución a esto»_, me aseguré investigando.  _«Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre»_ Me parece que lo estoy encaminando. Si no, házmelo saber e intentaré ayudarlo de mejor manera. Saludos.